# Android change string language

Tags: android

I am using takephoto_library for selecting multiple images.

https://github.com/crazycodeboy/TakePhoto

It is working properly but as you can see in the below screenshot, the caption is in Chinese.

I found that the view control is "com.darsh.multipleimageselect.activities" and Id of this caption is in the below

```
 actionBar.setTitle(R.string.album_view);
```

Is there any way to change this string to English?

[image]

Comment: you want to change "已选" to english ?

Comment: @JohnJoe Yes mate

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

find the `strings.xml`(values) and `strings.xml(values-en)` in the library of `TakePhoto` .

And change the string name to the English .

In the `strings.xml`(values)

```
string name="add">确定</string>
<string name="selected">已选</string>
<string name="limit_exceeded">最多能选 %d 张</string>
```

And add this to the `strings.xml`(values-en)

```
string name="add">confirm</string>
<string name="selected">selected</string>
<string name="limit_exceeded">You can choose%d at most</string>
```

And you can change this [strings.xml(values-en)](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/TakePhoto/tree/master/takephoto_library/src/main/res/values-en) and [strings.xml(values)](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/TakePhoto/tree/master/takephoto_library/src/main/res/values)

Comment: I'm going to try it now

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to change this string to English?

Yes, you can change all the Strings in `strings.xml`

https://github.com/crazycodeboy/TakePhoto/blob/master/takephoto_library/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

Change these two chinese word to english

```
<string name="add">确定</string>
<string name="selected">已选</string>
```

In English

```
 <string name="add">confirm</string>
 <string name="selected">selected</string>
```

Comment: @KeLiuyue takephoto_library is added to my project as a jar. Should I remove it from the gradle and add it as a project?

Comment: Not really sure but I don't think you can change it if it is a library. Why not add it as manual instead of library ?

Comment: at worst, I will do that. Many thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

For internationalization, android looks in different directories for the appropriate local as determined by your selection for the phone.  For instance, you should see something like this:

```
./explorer/src/main/res/values-uk/strings.xml
./explorer/src/main/res/values-tr/strings.xml
./explorer/src/main/res/values-ru/strings.xml
./explorer/src/main/res/values-pl/strings.xml
./explorer/src/main/res/values-de/strings.xml
./explorer/src/main/res/values-ko/strings.xml
./explorer/src/main/res/values-sv/strings.xml
...
```

Where the translated strings are in the values-../strings as determined by the res/values/strings.xml.
In my case, res/values/strings.xml has an entry:

```
<string name="createnewfolder">Create new folder</string>
```

which is translated in values-uk/strings.xml as

```
<string name="createnewfolder">Нова папка</string>
```

You might find [Localizing with Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) useful.